# Cannot get my own JS file to work with Wordpress (4.9).

Tags: wordpress

I am in a bit of a pickle, lol.

Here is my function:

```
  function start_group_escapes_4_less() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ge4l', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/js/ge4l.js', array('jquery'), null, true);

  }

  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'start_group_escapes_4_less' );
```

Everywhere I checked, the syntax is right. Or is it?
Help :(

Comment: In what file are you executing this? Is the css file being added?

Answer (score 2):

The function `get_stylesheet_uri()` return the url of the theme style.css file.

You need to use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`

```
function start_group_escapes_4_less() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ge4l', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ge4l.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'start_group_escapes_4_less' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the directory of the files `style.css` and `ge4l.js` are correct and appropriate to the wp-admin file. Or try puting **~** sign at the directory shown in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of return => `<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>`

Use `get_template_directory()` ?!

Comment: that was it >.>